# How to scroll and loop a texture's red component up down left and right efficiently in html5 Canvas?

Tags: html, loops, canvas, scroll

```
 <code>
 var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 var img1 = new Image();
//drawing of the test image - img1
img1.onload = function () {
    //draw background image
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 280);
};
img1.src = 'grass60.png';
var imgData = ctx.createImageData(521, 280);
var i;
var count=0
for (i = 0 ; i < imgData.data.length;i+=4) {
imgData.data[i] = imgData.data[i+2084%583520];
imgData.data[i+1] = imgData.data[i+1%583520];
imgData.data[i+2] = imgData.data[i+2%583520];
imgData.data[i+3] = 255;
}
ctx.putImageData(imgData,0, 0);
//or
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var img1 = new Image();

//drawing of the test image - img1
img1.onload = function () {
    //draw background image
    ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
};

img1.src = 'grass60.png';
//Code below that produces black screen
var imgData = ctx.createImageData(521, 280);

var i;
var DB = new Uint8Array(256);

for (var qq=0;qq<256;qq++){
DB[qq]=qq;
}
var count=0
for (i = 0 ; i < imgData.data.length;i+=4) {

imgData.data[i] = imgData.data[(i+2048)%583520]
imgData.data[i+1] = imgData.data[(i+1)%583520]
imgData.data[i+2] = imgData.data[(i+2)%583520]
imgData.data[i+3] = 255;
}

ctx.putImageData(imgData,0, 280);
</code>
```

//This won't draw the image only all black or nothing.
The above code doesn't work can't access the image not sure why
The grass is just an image that has some redder elements in it.
The code was to alter the image data but it just creates a blank screen

Comment: scrolling is like this x and y but red only http://codetheory.in/moving-scrolling-sliding-background-in-html5-canvas/

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question "why does it create a blank screen?" is that you're reading `img1`'s data before `img1` is loaded. Almost all your code should be in the onload.

Other problems you have:

- You are creating a brand new empty ImageData full of 0s, and then copying its data around inside itself. (I discovered this by adding `console.log(imgData.data.slice(i, i+4));` to your for loop.) This will also give you a blank screen. You need to gather the original image's data with a line like

  ```
  var oldImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 280, 521, 280);
  ```
- Shifting the red pixels down by 2084 will be barely noticeable -- a line one pixel wide at the top. Try 20840 so you can see the effect.
- This code would have been much clearer if instead of the "magic number" 583520, you had used `imgData.length` or `var bytes = img.width * img.height * 4;`. It wasn't needed, anyway; this works just fine:

  `newImageData.data[i+20840] = oldImageData.data[i];`

Edit: [Here's a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Noumenon72/r8yfx3n7/), now that I got a base64 image to use.

Comment: var imgData = ctx.createImageData(521, 280);
    ctx.putImageData(imgData,0, 280);//changing these lines does the same thing

Comment: var oldImageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 280, 521, 280); This command fails to read the image breaking the code

Comment: Some Stack etiquette: don't just throw up code and expect people to get it in an editor and debug it for you. Read the page on [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I decided to help anyway (even downloaded my own 521x280 image) and produced working code (http://pastebin.com/h1PJue2b), just because I was interested. Since this was learning code with several different problems, I thought it was more helpful to guide you toward the answer than to simply correct it. It's more than most people will do for a question that's basically "it doesn't work".

Comment: that doesn't change the image just loads it.

Comment: You may be running into the cross-origin request problem from working locally; see if there's a complaint in your browser console. Regardless, here's a live working example, shifting yellow instead of red:
https://jsfiddle.net/Noumenon72/r8yfx3n7/

Comment: Seems likely to be an issue with the browser you're using. At any rate, "why doesn't this JSFiddle work on Ubuntu?" is a different question. Considering that I have not even gotten any karma for the hour I put into solving *this* question, I'm not inclined to start working on that one. Especially since you're phrasing it not as "Thanks for the answer, I have a follow-up question" but more like "You owe me a cross-platform solution and updates until I'm satisfied".

Comment: I tried it at the WC3 schools site and it didn't work in a text html how exactly are you formating the image so it works in JSfiddle

Comment: If you use, say, `http://imgur.com/myImg.jpg`, it won't work, because of the cross-origin "tainting" I referred to earlier. `getImageData` is designed not to let you copy off-site images. In the fiddle, I used a Base64 encoded image for `img.src`, avoiding this problem -- try copying that string to use for your image. Working that out is one of the reasons I didn't post a fiddle in the first place. To get it working at home, I had to run a server in the folder where the code ran; opening `file:///my.html` with `img src='myImage.jpg'` would have the same cross-origin request problem.

Comment: @Infinity8378 I'd appreciate if you accepted this answer; I can tell you how to avoid the CORS issue locally if that's still giving you trouble.

Comment: Accept! Accept! Sorry, karma hungry here.